# Integrating E-signature for KYC in the web to lead form

Tags: salesforce1-app

I'm currently working on a project that involves integrating E-signature functionality into a web-to-lead form for KYC (Know Your Customer) purposes. It needs to be compatible with MobilePhone,IPAD etc.,, Customer needs to sign a form to verify that they have read terms and conditions. I have a question like What E-signature APIs are recommended for seamless integration with web-to-lead forms. I appreciate any insights, recommendations, or resources that can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

You can refer to this video if you like to use DocuSign in Salesforce for your application :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZjL9ggwMTY&t=607s

Comment: Thanks for your response. we are trying to integrating esignature in the web to lead form but not inside the salesforce.

Comment: You can add the piece of code in web-to-lead also !